# How to prove a turing machine is decidable which accepts ⟨A, B⟩ | A and B are NFAs and L(A) ⊆ L(B).

Tags: turing-machines, decidability

So I'm trying to construct a Turing machine M = = {⟨A, B⟩ | A and B are NFAs and L(A) ⊆ L(B)}. I was wondering how to approach this problem as there are total 4 possibilities -

1. A accepts A
2. B accepts A
3. A accepts B
4. B accepts B

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are using the terminology incorrectly. Firstly, languages, not Turing machines, can be decidable. Secondly, automata accept strings, not automata. For these reasons, it is unfortunately hard to make sense of what you are writing.

Comment: To prove this, you need to find an algorithm so that given 2 NFAs $A$ and $B$, it can always decide if the language accepted by $A$ is the subset of the language accepted by $B$. For example, let NFA $A$ be given by the regex $01$ and NFA $B$ be given by the regex $01^*$. Then $L(A) = \{01\}$ is clearly a subset of $L(B) = \{01, 011, 0111, \dots\}$. **Hint**: To come up with an algorithm, the key property you need to use is that "$L(A) \subseteq L(B)$ if and only if $L(A) \setminus L(B) = \emptyset$"